# Generalized Triangle Inequality for Snowflakes

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $p>0$ and consider a metric space $(X,d)$.  I have recently come across a problem where the space $(X,d^q)$ provides is natural; where $q>1$.  However, the triangle inquality break (i.e. it is a ["semimetric space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Semimetrics)).

I'm wondering, in this case, does $(X,d^p)$ satisfy some kind of "generalized triangle inequality"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, let $p>1$ and $a,b>0$, and set $\tilde{d}:X\times X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
\tilde{d}(x,z)\mapsto a \,d(x,z) + b\,d(x,z)^p \qquad (\text{ for all }x,z\in X) 
$$
Then, for every $x,y,z\in X$ we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{d}(x,z) = &\, a \,d(x,z) + b\,d(x,z)^p \\
\le  & a(d(x,y)+d(y,z)) + b(d(x,y)+d(y,z))^p\\
\le & a(d(x,y)+d(y,z)) + 2^{p-1}\,b(d(x,y)^p+d(y,z)^p)\\
\le & 2^{p-1}\,a(d(x,y)+d(y,z)) + 2^{p-1}\,b(d(x,y)^p+d(y,z)^p)\\
= & 2^{-1}\big(\tilde{d}(x,y)+\tilde{d}(x,z)\big).
\end{aligned}
$$

For more details, see [Qinglan Xia - The Geodesic Problem in Quasimetric Space, J. Geom. Anal. 2009](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12220-008-9065-4).